# Incredibly persistent nullpointerexception (java/processing)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, processing

-Problem-
so im trying to make a program in processing (which i'm running with java, so its based on java).
The program makes a grid of 3dimensional points and does stuff with them. right now its drawing small circles on them to verify that its working. i was in the process of debugging to find why all the circles werent drawing and i somehow created an error i cant get rid of. no matter what i do theres always a nullpointerexception error on line 43. ive tried making a new script file and copy+pasting the code into there, restarting the processing IDE, etc, but nothing seems to fix it. I can add statements above or below to manipulate which line is 43 but it doesn't change the error.. anyone here familiar with processing that can help me out? i dont know how to interpret the error message outside of reading it as "look at line 43 for something being called as a null" so thats why im confused.

-Code-

```
int sizex = 20;
int sizey = 20;
int framewidth = 800;
int frameheight = 800;
int[][] points = new int[(framewidth/sizex+1)*(frameheight/sizey+1)][];

void setup(){
  noLoop();
  background(255);
  size(framewidth,frameheight,P3D);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);

  for(int x = 0; x<=framewidth/sizex; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y<=frameheight/sizey; y++){
      int[] point =  {x*sizex,y*sizey,0};
      //print("\nx:"+x+" y:"+y+" place:"+place);
      points[x*(framewidth/sizex)+y] = point;
      //place++;
    }
  }
}

void draw(){
  int sinstep = 0;
  for(int count = 0; count < points.length; count++){
    int[] temp = points[count];
    temp[2]=(int)(100*Math.sin(sinstep/100));
    points[count] = temp;
  }
  sinstep++;

  for(int x = 0; x<=framewidth/sizex; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y<=frameheight/sizey; y++){
      //print(x+", "+y);
      int[] p = {1,2,3};
      find(x,y);
      ellipse(p[0],p[1],10,10);  
      }
   }
}
void find(int x, int y){
  print("yourmom");
  //This is where the error is //int[] temp = points[(x-1)*(framewidth/sizex)+y
  int[] z = {x,y,x+y};
}
```

-Error Message-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:206)
at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:172)
at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:191)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:541)
at processing.opengl.PJOGL.requestDraw(PJOGL.java:688)
at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1651)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at *triangles.draw(triangles.java:43)*
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:302)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: which line is line 43?

Comment: It's probably the `points` array not being initialized correctly. The code `int[][] points = new int[(framewidth/sizex+1)*(frameheight/sizey+1)][];` leaves the second dimension uninitialized.

Comment: Your draw() function is a mess. And why are you using a 2D array instead of making a Point class or something like that?

Comment: @Eizooz, can you print temp.length in your draw function, right after you assign it? Pretty sure that's where your bug is, but I can't tell without looking at the whole code.

Comment: 43 is marked by the comment //This is where the error is, but it is on the line of another comment so its confusing. although like i explained, the line doesnt change or follow any piece of code.

im using a 2d array because i was having trouble finding a point class that supported dimensions and i dont know how to make my own yet.

this is my whole code.

Comment: You're not running the code above. Maybe you simply forgot to recompile it? Or you're using the wrong classpath?

Answer (score 0):

it was the array instantiation. now sure how that was causing the error message in a seemingly unrelated part but it works now so cool.